# How to fix error of path?

Tags: html, css

I have access to my site through `index.php`. It works good but when I add a slash, for example `index.php/`, then my `CSS` style disappears.
How to fix this error or what I do incorrectly?

Comment: Is your CSS file being included via a relative `href`?

Comment: yes by a relative href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an absolute URL to reference your CSS file instead. Adding a slash after the URL makes the browser think that `index.php` is a directory, and thus it tries to find the CSS file relative to that "directory."

Comment: If your `index.php` file is located at `http://www.example.com/site/index.php`, and your CSS file `styles.css` is in the same folder, then you can reference your CSS file by using  `href="http://www.example.com/site/styles.css"`.

Comment: the css file is in /css/  not in the same folder for index.php

Comment: Then adjust the URL accordingly.

Comment: I dont't think thats a good solution ,,,I tried adding ,,/  it worked when there is a /   but  ./ works when there is no slash ,,so what is the point ?

Comment: You're still using a relative URL if there's a `../` anywhere in it. This will always be susceptible to your problem. Switch to absolute URLs (or root-relative URLs) to solve the issue.